# How can I get slice colors of piechart in ZoomCharts?

Tags: zoomcharts

After call drawchart function, how can i get particular slice color of PieChart of Zoomcharts.

Is there any method that give me current color of Slice.

Answer (score 0):

Call `chart.getActivePies()`;

This object will contain array of the active pies. In each pie object you will have `allSlices` array of slice objects. Each slice object has a property `currentFillColor` which contains the values that you need.